# Switch case not taking variable

Tags: shell-script

I have the following switch case in the script:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  case "$1" in
    -f|--file)
      shift
      f=$1
      ;;
    -s|--string)
      s=$2
      shift
      ;;
    -c|--client)
      c=$3
      shift
      ;;
    -h|-help)
      _usage
      ;;
    -*)
      _usage
    ;;
  esac
 shift
done
```

When I run this though, I can never get the `-c` passed with the String i pass it. It always is blank. I am not sure why this is the case since the first two vars are passed (i.e -f and -s). Can someone advise why this might be occurring?

Here is what I do, expecting that ybdemo would be passed to -c:

```
./find_prod_andfix.sh -f /etc/bar/active_clients -s foo -c "ybdemo"

Mon Aug 27 14:51:22 EDT 2018 find_prod_andfix.sh 11351 INFO: /etc/bar/active_clients
Mon Aug 27 14:51:22 EDT 2018 find_prod_andfix.sh 11351 INFO: foo
Mon Aug 27 14:51:22 EDT 2018 find_prod_andfix.sh 11351 INFO:
Mon Aug 27 14:51:22 EDT 2018 find_prod_andfix.sh 11351 INFO: Checking -- Client ID:
```

This is where in the script I echo out the info above:

```
if [[ -z $c ]]; then
    _info ${f}
    _info ${s}
    _info ${c}
    _info "Checking ${line} --  Client ID: ${CLIENT_ID}"
fi
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Run your script with `set -x` enabled and I believe you will see that you are `shift`ing things and then still looking at `$3` when you should be looking at `$1` or `$2` depending on where you `shift` (you are inconsistent about this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're outsmarting yourself with your use of `shift`:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  case "$1" in
    -f|--file)
      f="$2" # Re-ordered for consistency
      shift
      ;;
    -s|--string)
      s="$2"
      shift
      ;;
    -c|--client)
      c="$2"   # this was $3, which was the error
      shift
      ;;
    -h|-help)
      _usage
      ;;
    -*)
      _usage
    ;;
  esac
 shift
done
```

Comment: You are right... Just tried it and it worked.